# Magento Tracking Number from Order Object

Tags: magento, magento-1.4

Given a magento order object how can I find the tracking number associated with that order?

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId(100000064);

$shipmentCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_shipment_collection')
    ->setOrderFilter($order)
    ->load();
foreach ($shipmentCollection as $shipment){
    // This will give me the shipment IncrementId, but not the actual tracking information.
    $shipment->getData(); 
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3155671/magento-cronjob-outside-magento-to-update-shipment-status some relevant code here.

Comment: An answer that helped me while googling for this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9433627/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the code below: Its not tested though.

```
$shipment->getAllTracks();
```

Comment: I got Blank Array When I use this code in sales_order_shipment_save_after Observer event.

Answer (score 9):

I struggled over this one too, returning null values. Finally figured it out though. First, as previously noted, retrieve the shipment collection associated with the given order:

```
$shipmentCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_shipment_collection')
            ->setOrderFilter($order)
        ->load();
        foreach ($shipmentCollection as $shipment){
            // This will give me the shipment IncrementId, but not the actual tracking information.
            foreach($shipment->getAllTracks() as $tracknum)
            {
                $tracknums[]=$tracknum->getNumber();
            }

        }
```

The array $tracknums will now contain each of the tracking numbers linked to this order/shipment.

Comment: I got Blank Array When I use this code in sales_order_shipment_save_after Observer event.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply do this:

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId(100000064);
$trackNumber = array();
foreach ($order->getTracksCollection() as $track){
    $trackNumber[] = $track->getNumber();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

use

```
$order->getTrackingNumbers()
```

Answer (score -1):

It should be

```
Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_shipment_collection')
    ->setOrderFilter($order)
    ->load();
```