# Can I load all shipping methods automatically on the shopping cart page without selecting a country first?

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.8

Can I load all my shipping methods automatically on the shopping cart page without prior to selecting a country?

By Magento default, you have to select your country where you want to ship your order to. Then you have to hit the button **'Get a quote'** for the '**Estimate Shipping and Tax**'. But I want to skip this step by showing all my shipping methods automatically as soon as you are on this page.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check

[Programatically retrieve list of all shipping methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9433627/programatically-retrieve-list-of-all-shipping-methods)

http://www.pixlpitch.com/how-to-get-all-active-shipping-methods/

http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/280208/